# Google Analytics not saving screen_name event parameter

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am using Google Analytics to track screen views in a web-based SPA. On navigation, screen_view event is fired with the screen_name parameter as below:

```
gtag('event', 'screen_view', {
                'screen_name': screenName,
            });
```

The parameter is sent and displayed in real time data at the Analytics site, however I can't manage to display it in any report (even if I define the parameter as a dimension in a report, it looks like there's no data attached to it). I am definitely overlooking something simple, but I can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you care using GA4 free, wait some time (at least 24 hrs) before you can use them in your reports

Comment: Yes, I know, but the data has been collected for a while now. The events get populated and all, only without this property.